# NodeJS+express server route hangs

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, passport.js

I have a default NodeJS express server setup with passport auth. The server is working behind the Nginx proxy.

The problem is that after some time of uptime any route can just hang and not respond to requests. Is there some known issue with that or has anyone encountered with that? Is there any workaround?

After I restart the app it works fine.

Thank you.

Comment: This is not a typical problem. Please add code of your app and nginx configuration.

Comment: This is not a known aspect of node.js, but some sort of problem with your specific code.  My wild guess would be some sort of resource leak (db connection, file handle, etc...) and eventually you exhaust internal resources and the app will no longer work properly.  But, ,there's literally  NOTHING we can do but make a wild guess when you don't give us any debugging info and show no code.

Comment: I'm afraid it is impossible to reproduce this issue cause even I'm not able to do it. The app can run fine for days, weeks or month and then single route can hang (while other routes continue to work fine). I guess if it was an exhaust of internal resoucres than the app didn't work at all. But the strange thing is that only a single route does not. I just thought maybe it is a known behaviour.